# First statement of a constructor

Tags: groovy, gradle

I've written the following simplest script:

```
task init << {
    println "init";
}

task hello(dependsOn: init) << {
    println "hello";
}

task super(dependsOn: hello) << {
    println "super"
}
```

But I got an error when I tried to execute `gradle super`:

```
build file 'D:\gradle\build.gradle': 9: Constructor call must be the first statement in 
a constructor. at line: 9 column: 12.
File: build_69b6a3lkqqtk7j84lsls47ccta @ line 9, column 12.
     task super(dependsOn: hello) << {
```

What's a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`super` is Groovy's reserved keyword for invoking parent class constructor. Change it to e.g. `super2` and run `gradle super2`, it will work.